# Reducing git repo size for github

Tags: git, github

So i have a firefox repository with full history. I made some changes in it and now want to push it on my own repository on github.

However the problem is that the size of repo is 2.3 GB and github won't accept anything greater than 2gb.

What are my options for safely reducing the size to 2gb. I have read some of the answers and i am not really sure if they would not break anything in firefox.

Comment: Not without altering the repository, no.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/ not so much info but still...

Comment: Is there anything you can do to remove some files ? logs / compiled sources / third party binaries you could add as external resources ? maybe use a CDN for some of your resources ?

Comment: @Franck i am really new to firefox source. Git already doesn't track the compiled binaries i am not really sure what else i can remove without breaking something somewhere

Comment: did you fork a specific repo? it seems you are trying to push that code into another repo ? you should fork it

Comment: it is like this. I cloned from the firefox git repo on github. After that i made some changes in the firefox source. Now i am trying to upload the code in a new repo on github. Problem is that once it reaches 2gb the source stops uploading because of the hard limit of github. Now i am not sure what can i remove from the firefox without breaking it